# Crystal Reports any way to change orientation of only one page?

Tags: image, crystal-reports, rotation

I'm trying to change an individual page within a multi-page report so that the orientation is landscape instead of portrait. The page contains only images, and I'd like for them to be displayed sideways. Is there a way of doing this?

Barring that, is there a way of rotating the images themselves? The images are dynamically added to the page through a datasource that contains a path string to the image on disk. The only way I can think of is to make a copy of the images, rotate them, then provide a path to the temporary images, but this method is a bit roundabout.

Comment: (LOLz @ Lowe's comment)

What version of CR are you using? I think the latest version, CR 2008, allows this ability.

Comment: Crystal Reports 11. I ended up 'fixing' this problem by rotating the images. It's kludgy, but hopefully after this project we'll be switching over to Sql Reporting Services.

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you rotate an image object with a crystal formula? As far as I know you cannot switch between portrait and landscape, at least you can't in XI.